# what does mean by rewritten box during yolo training on custom dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, yolo

I am training my custom dataset on Yolo network and during training, I am getting info of rewritten box (as shown in the figure).

for example: total_bbox = 29159, rewritten_bbox = 0.006859 %

what does that mean? Is my training proceeding right?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJm1Y.png)

Answer (score -3):

optimal numbers of layers and resolution depend on dataset.
The smaller objects - the higher resolution is required.
The large objects - the more layers are required. There is an article on choosing the optimal number of layers, filters and resolution for MS COCO dataset: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.09070.pdf

It depends on what accuracy and speed do you want. To reduce rewritten_bbox % just increase resolution and/or move some masks from [yolo] layers with low resolution, the [yolo] layers with higher resolution, and train. Also iou_thresh=1 may reduce rewritten_bbox %